# First item on list always an empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to render items where each item has an item Name, item Price, and Item photos, like a todo list which works well but the first item on the list is always an empty array.

```
// Store State
  const [itemName, setItemName] = useState('');
  const [itemPrice, setItemPrice] = useState('');
  const [photoArray, setPhotoArray] = useState([]);
  const [storeItems, setStoreItems] = useState([]);

const addItem = {
    id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 11),
    itemName: itemName, 
    itemPrice: itemPrice,
    photo: photoArray
  };

const addStoreItem = () => {
      if (itemName == '' || itemPrice == '') {
          Alert.alert('Error', 'Please fill in the item detail.')
      } else {
          Keyboard.dismiss();
          setStoreItems([...storeItems, addItem]);
          setItemName(null);
          setItemPrice(null);
          setPhotoArray([]);
      };
  };
```

I'm rendering the item list in a bottomsheet Modal before adding it to the screen.
PhotoArray

```
const pickPhoto = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      quality: 0.2,
    });

    if (!result.cancelled) {
        setPhotoArray([...photoArray, result.uri]);
    }
  };
```

Render in bottomsheet modal

```
{storeItems.map((item, index) => {
       return (
        <View key={index.toString()} style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginBottom: 10, marginTop: 5}}>
          <AddStoreItem  items={item}/>                                    
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.cancel} key={index} onPress={() => deleteItem(index)}>
               <Image source={icons.cross} style={styles.cancelIcon}/>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
             )
           })
         }
```

Send StoreItems to screen

```
const store = () => {
        setStoreItems([...storeItems, addItem]);
        storeRef?.current?.close();
        Keyboard.dismiss();
  };
```

Header component that has the submit button

```
<ModalHeader left={toggleStoreModalClose} right={store} />
```

Render in screen

```
{Array.from(Array(numColumns)).map((col, colIndex) => (
                              <View style={{flex: 1}} key={colIndex}>
                              {photoArray
                              .filter((item, index) => index % numColumns === colIndex)
                              .map((item, index) => (
                                  <View key={index.toString()} style={styles.photoContainer}>                                
                                      <Image source={{uri: item}} style={styles.addedPhoto}/>
                                  </View>
                              ))}
                          </View>
                          ))
                        }
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

That's because in this line

```
setStoreItems([...storeItems, addItem]);
```

you are spreading `storeItems` which is initially set to `[]` empty array, thus the issue of first item as empty array

Comment: I don't believe this is correct-- spreading an empty array into an array won't result in an empty entry or empty array, it will essentially be a no-op.  [See this fiddle for an example of what I mean](https://jsfiddle.net/anied/zgey2a4k/2/).

Comment: Thanks to you both. Alexander Nied do you have the correct way of going about this?

Comment: @AlexanderNied yes you're correct, my mistake, but when i ran the OP's code in codesandbox, it works fine for me, i don't get an empty array
[see this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-varahamihira-fbz4pr?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. This indicates that @abdulrashidado 's question does not include a sufficient [mcve] for us to reproduce their issue; as such, I would say it is perhaps unanswerable until the question is updated to provide enough context for us to actually see and understand the problem they are facing.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back. I made some updates to my code.

Answer (score 0):

Found the Problem. Was passing addItem again in the function to the submit button

Before

```
 const store = () => {
        setStoreItems([...storeItems, addItem]);
        storeRef?.current?.close();
        Keyboard.dismiss();
  };
```

And After

```
 const store = () => {
        setStoreItems([...storeItems]);
        storeRef?.current?.close();
        Keyboard.dismiss();
  };
```

Thanks for all the effort.